# open and write commands in command prompt from subprocess.Popen python in Windows 10

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt

I want to write python script to run a program in command prompt in Windows 10 (64 bit).

My current working directory is '`C:\Python\Project`'.
My target is to change this working directory to '`D:\Calculation`' and to view the content of the files by typing in 'dir'. I've searched and looked through the official documents but I can't find how I can do this.

This works well:

```
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', 'cd /d d:\Calculation'], shell = True)
```

However, that doesn't work:

```
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', 'cd /d d:\Calculation', '&', 'dir'], shell = True)
```

But this works (I can see both command prompt (its location successfully changed to 'd:\Calculation' and the notepad application opened):

```
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', 'cd /d d:\Calculation', '&', 'notepad.exe'], shell = True)
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar problem, this code should work:

```
subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd', '/k', 'cd /d d:\Calculation & dir'], shell = True)
```

The trick is to include the '&' stuff with the command.